# I am trying an Multiply App where I need to change variable after submission form without reload

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, submission

I need to change the variable after the submission form without reloading. So that I can next time get new num1 and num2 veritable with new correntAns and can check the correct answer.

Please see my code here; I need correctAns variable change after the submission form every time.

```
    formEl.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    const userAns = +inputEl.value;
    //console.log(userAns, typeof userAns);
    inputEl.value = "";
    inputEl.focus();

    if(userAns === correntAns){
            score++;
            submitCount++;
        const num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
        const num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
        let correntAns = num1 * num2;

    }else{
            // score--;
            submitCount++;
    }
    scoreEl.innerText = `Score: ${score}/${submitCount}`;
```

});

Comment: Here is the more code which is before the addEventListener Method: 

`const num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10); 
const num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10); 
let correntAns = num1 * num2;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [XML ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to submit the form without loading

you can change variable after form submission without loading in AJAX

Comment: Thanks for your response. Form value submit well but need next time check by new num1 and num2 as correntAns. correctAns variable remain same first value that was before submission form.